# freeing a structure array allocated with double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, free

Here is basically what I'm trying to do:

free memory that was allocated in a different scope using double pointers.
The following code is incomplete but fully describes what I'm trying to perform.

so here is my function to read the buffer (C pseudo code)

```
 char *read_buffer(char *buf, myStruct **arr, int nbElm)
 {
     buf = malloc(...);
     ...//many things done (use of the read(),close()... functions
     ...//but not referencing any of the buffer to my structure
     ...
     *arr = (myStruct *) = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * nbElm);
     return (buf);
 }
```

Here is the kind of function I use between my memory allocation and my freeing attempt:

```
 void using_struct(myStruct *ar, int nbElm)
 {
     int i;

     i = 0;
     while (i < nbElm)
     {
         // Here I use my struct with no problems
         // I can even retrieve its datas in the main scope
         // not memory is allocated to it.
     }
 }
```

my main function :

```
int main(void)
{
    char *buf;
    myStruct *arStruct;
    int nbElm = 4;

    buf = read_buffer(buf, &arStruct, nbElm);
    using_struct(arStruct, nbElm);
    free(buf);
    buf = NULL;
    free(arStruct);
    while(1)
    {;}
    return (1);
}
```

The only problem is either I place my while loop before or after my free function,  I can't see any memory change using **top**
on my terminal.
Is this normal?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you should `free` `asStruct` only one time and not in loop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always must have exactly same number of calls to free as a calls to malloc.

```
myStruct **arr;
*arr = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * nbElm);
```

This means you need single call to free first nbElm structs:

```
free(arr);
```

Comment: Hum ok this works, but when I freeze my program I can't see memory change in my program? (using top in my mac terminal)

Comment: I'll check again more carefully and tell you. Any advices (FYI leaks command doesn't work) Thx :).

Comment: @jonhatansmith if you want to check memory change debug your program and inspect memory with gdb x command, e.g x/4xw arr. Look at the VIRT column in top, not at the RES which is real used memory. If you don't actually write or read to memory you malloced, the OS might not give you this memory in reality, but only say that you will get it eventually if you try to write or read to that memory (and cause page fault in kernel). Use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to trace all system calls made by your program.

Comment: thx I'll look at that. For now on I just can use lldb, but I guess its the same thing?

Comment: no, lldb is a debugger, like gdb, while strace is a program for tracing of system calls and signals

Comment: Well many thx! Tinky_Winky!!! Already toldy you were my fav one in Teletubbyland?!!